# Ubuntu installation stuck at ‘updates and other software’

Tags: system-installation

When I try to install Ubuntu, the process gets stuck at ‘updates and other software’.  I waited for a long time but nothing happened.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this bug is what you describe:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1766978

If so, try mounting and unmounting the Windows boot partition until the installer detects it and prompts you to unmount it.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I tried mounting/unmounting all my windows related partition and it worked! Thanks.